# I need help with putting together a battery

Tags: voltage, batteries, amperage, watts, diy

I want to make a 14V, 5A battery out of DIY crystal cells. Each cell is about 1.5V and 0.3A

I know I can connect on series until I get my desired voltage, but I need to increase the amps.

Is there a way to increase the amp output using capacitors, resistors etc.?
Should I connect in series until I get 70W and then use capacitors, resistors etc.?

Edit:
I need 60 to 70 Watts output power to be able to power my electronics.

Comment: Put 20 strings of 10 batteries in parallel and that will give you 15 V, 6 A.

Comment: I thought putting batteries in parallel only increases Ah/Wh..

Comment: I need the output to be at least 5A consistently to be able to power my fan, radio and LED lights

Comment: I need 60Watt power at least (5A on my 12V system)

Comment: Fair warning: ‘Crystal battery’ appears to be in the marginal ‘woo’ pseudoscience category. At first look there seems to be no peer-reviewed research on them with meaningful comparisons to other battery technologies, despite them being around for a long time.

Comment: Without detailed knowledge of their characteristics, proposing using them in series/parallel is a problem, as imbalances can cause catastrophic failures with cells that have low internal resistance (like Li-ion).

Comment: I'm not worried about the lack of peer-reviewed research, I'll test and retest before it goes on my boat. I just need help with getting power up to 70W

Comment: I respect everyone's concerns, but I asked here for a reason: To get technical advice. If I wanted to have an arbitrary debate on whether it's considered a good idea or not I would have posted on reddit

Comment: You can buy ‘lead crystal’ batteries today with suitable capacity. These are field-proven.

Comment: On the other hand, if Hutchinson’s battery were the real deal there’d be replicated results at places like Sandia Labs. Nothing like that exists as far as I can tell.

Comment: If it was profitable business practice to sell batteries that run 5 to 10 years on a single charge maybe

Comment: Yeah… no. If such a battery with that much of an energy density advantage existed it would have been built and commercialized a long time ago. There’s just too much at stake for there to be a global conspiracy to hold it back. As it is, lithium batteries have shelf life that long (low internal discharge), which is maybe what you mean by ‘5 to 10 years on a single charge’.

Comment: @ErikSVCashFlow "before it goes on my boat" - is that a real boat or a model boat? I'd be concerned about something that could catch fire on a real boat.

Comment: "*I asked here for a reason: To get technical advice.*" That's what you're getting. Many of us are professional electrical engineers with decades of experience. You would do well to listen. "*I thought putting batteries in parallel only increases Ah/Wh.*" It also increases maximum available current. If one string can provide 0.3 A then two in parallel can provide 0.6 A (subject to proper balancing between each string).

Comment: @Transistor Thank you. I didn't know that series connection also increases available current. The crystal cells are really hard to balance as they don't charge or discharge, once they're built the voltage and amperage is pretty much fixed. As far as I've seen on smaller scale experiments they don't heat up or show any other sign of fire or explosion risk when connected in series or parallel though. I'll take everyone's warnings into consideration and be extra careful.. let it sit and carry a 60W load in a controlled area for at least 3 months while I monitor it's behaviour before using it.

Comment: @Transistor sorry I meant to write *parallel

Comment: @hacktastical These have been commercially available for at least 7 years: https://youtu.be/3EKmetdjE-c and they're based on John Hutchinson's research... Here is a clip where they mention his Japanese funding: https://youtu.be/cHvimKQebVg ... If it doesn't make a profit it's not worth selling. That's not a conspiracy it's just common business sense

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is Transistor's:

> Put 20 strings of 10 batteries in parallel and that will give you 15 V, 6 A

Obviously that's a lot of batteries, but if they put out 0.3A (how is that measured, short circuit current?), that's what you need. Each battery puts out slightly less than one watt.

> Should I connect in series until I get 70W and then use capacitors, resistors etc.?

It's actually viable to connect them all in a big string and use a buck converter to give you the voltage you need; these can readily be bought as modules.

The downside is that's going to be all 80 batteries in a single string, so the 120V safety starts to be an issue.

Comment: ‘Safety starts to be an issue’ at about 60V DC. More here: https://www.edn.com/what-does-selv-mean-for-power-supplies/

Comment: Thank you pjc50. I'll start looking into buck converters 

Comment: @pjc50 yes 0.3A short circuit current